# Нужна ли запятая: "Осуществляется, сообразуясь"?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли ставить запятую в предложении: «правосудие осуществляется, сообразуясь с определенными принципами»?

Answer (score 3):

На мой взгляд, вся конструкция не верна. Начало предложения представляет собой страдательную конструкцию! Деепричастный оборот употреблять нельзя.  Правосудие ни с чем не сообразуется. Это те. кто вершит правосудие. сообразуются с принципами.

Далее. Предположим, Вы исправили предложение. "Они вершат правосудие, сообразуясь с принципами...". Все равно это не деепричастие.  Я считаю, что это уже производный предлог. (**сообразуясь с**  принципами - т.е. **по** принципам. Другие предлоги, образованные от деепричастия: не считая,  судя по,  спустя

А запятая ставится, так же как при подобном предлоге. образованном от деепричастия - "несмотря на"

Comment: Полность согласен. Субъект (производитель действия "осуществляется") здесь не правосудие, из-за этого деепричастную конструкцию не к чему "прицепить".

Answer (score 2):

> При деепричастном обороте запятые ставятся  всегда. 
> "Он бежал сломя голову" –  это фразеологизм, он деепричастным оборотом не является. 
> "Деревья стояли не шелохнувшись" –  здесь нет деепричастного оборота

Comment: А ещё "сломя голову" — это слова, а ещё — буквы. То, что это фразеологизм, не мешает этому обороту быть деепричастным.       
Грамота.ру:  "Деепричастия, как с пояснительными словами, так и без них, кроме таких одиночных деепричастий и деепричастных оборотов, которые примыкают непосредственно к сказуемому и по своему значению приближаются к наречию".

Comment: Соглашусь с Инной, сломя голову - не деепричастный оборот. Деепричастие обозначает добавочное действие. Сломя голову - очень быстро. Вовсе не обязательно ломая что-нибудь. в том числе и голову.

Answer (score 1):

При деепричастном обороте запятые ставятся почти всегда. Исключения составляют устоявшиеся обороту (*"Он бежал сломя голову"*) и ситуации, когда деепричастный оборот тесно связан с сказумым (*"Деревья стояли не шелохнувшись"*). Пожалуй, второе стоит пояснить: важно не то, что деревья стояли, а то, что они стояли не шелохнувшись, в этом смысловая нагрузка, а сам по себе деепричастный оборот выражает добавочное действие.  
В вашем примере нет ни первого, ни второго, поэтому смело ставим запятую.

Comment: Судья впаял ему срок не задумываясь.